# Ignore spring properties file not found exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, config

I am using tomcat 6. My application context xml file contains this:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:#{contextParameters['my-filename']}"/>
</bean>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>my-filename</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want to do the following:

- At first the value of the `my-filename` will be empty, when the user runs the tomcat server he should be redirected to a config page where he can set the properties file location, I mean the `my-filename` value.
- After he clicks save I will update the web.xml file and restart tomcat server.

So now it is throwing an exception `FileNotFoundException` and not continuing. Can you tell me how can I suspect the file not found exception and redirect the user to the config page.

Comment: please check the path of file name given. the compiler is unable to find the file in the given path.so please check if it is given correctly.

Comment: @404 you should probably re-read the question

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)? In short set the `ignoreResourceNotFound` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a a default value pointing to some empty file you need to create:

```
<bean id="configLocation" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="file:#{contextParameters['my-filename']:./default-empty-file.properties}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" ref="configLocation"/>
</bean>
```

And then check if default value is in use:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("configLocation")
String configLocation;

final static String EMPTY_CONFIG_LOCATION = "file:./default-empty-file.properties";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String SomeAction(){
    if (EMPTY_CONFIG_LOCATION.equals(configLocation)) {
        // redirect
        return "redirect:configPage";
    } else {
        // do the normal stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Share in your controller...? Or do you even have spring application set up?